# A proper way to marshall an array of UInt32 to UInt8

Tags: swift

This

```
    let eByteArr = withUnsafeBytes(of: &entropySliceHashes32) { (bytes) -> [UInt8] in
        return bytes.map { $0 }
    }
```

somehow maps 16 bytes (four 4 byte unsigned ints) into 8 bytes:

```
(lldb) p entropySliceHashes32
([UInt32]) $R0 = 4 values {
  [0] = 414878621
  [1] = 3484496398
  [2] = 2937522763
  [3] = 3119551166
}

(lldb) p eByteArr
([UInt8]) $R1 = 8 values {
  [0] = 16
  [1] = 224
  [2] = 4
  [3] = 112
  [4] = 1
  [5] = 0
  [6] = 0
  [7] = 0
}
```

What's a succinct low overhead way to change representation of the underlying 16 byte heap in swift3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeremy already said, you have to call the `withUnsafeBytes` 
method on the array to get an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` to the element storage.

Now

- `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` is a `Collection` (and in particular a
  `Sequence`) of `UInt8`, and
- `Array` has a

  ```
  /// Creates an array containing the elements of a sequence.
  ///
  /// - Parameter s: The sequence of elements to turn into an array.
  public init<S>(_ s: S) where S : Sequence, S.Iterator.Element == Element
  ```

  initializer.

Therefore you can create an `[UInt8]` array from a raw buffer pointer
`ptr` with `Array(ptr)`:

```
let eByteArr = entropySliceHashes32.withUnsafeBytes {
    ptr in return Array(ptr)
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
let eByteArr = entropySliceHashes32.withUnsafeBytes { Array($0) }
```

Comment: @AntonTropashko: But the pointer isn't used outside the closure. The closure creates an array from the pointer and returns the array.

Comment: sadly, i don't understand how it works, but it does. hence the upvote :^) I assume both of the solutions proposed copy the entropy instead of reusing the existing storage

Comment: @AntonTropashko: I have added some more details. – Yes, creating an array will *always* copy the data. If you don't want that then you must use an UnsafeBufferPointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think your function is actually mapping the raw bytes of the array struct itself, not the contents.

I think you can get the expected result like this:

```
let eByteArr = entropySliceHashes32.withUnsafeBytes { 
    (bytes) -> [UInt8] in
    return bytes.map { $0 }
}
```

i.e. use the method on the array, not the free standing function.